# Airflow database performance impact due to multiple connection to database

Tags: postgresql, airflow

I have setup Airflow 1.10 to schedule python DAGs. I am also working on other project, which would need data from backend postgresql external database of Airflow (querying at every regular 5 min interval).

Now I am trying to understand the impact on Airflow database performance due to multiple connections on Airflow. Accordingly, I will plan my approach to get the data from Airflow database for other purpose